# Excel WorksheetFunction.XIRR and XIRR gave different answers from same input

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to do a project using VBA to complete an XIRR calculation. Parts of the code is as follows.

`Range("J3").Value = WorksheetFunction.IRR(IRRValues())
Range("J2").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Xirr(IRRValues(), RepayDates())`

`IRRValues()` is an array that contains every repayment that client makes and `RepayDates()` is an array that contains the corresponding dates of every repayment.

`IRRValues` starts with a negative number as the first cash out. But every time when I ran the VBA `WorksheetFunction.XIRR`, it gave me a number that's effectively 0. However, if I ran the same data in the worksheet using `=XIRR`, then it gave me another answer. And the `WorksheetFunction.IRR` works well. I've tried to change my local setting to "US" so date format is correct (mm/dd/yyyy).

Data is like the following and runs to 06/19/2012 with constant repayment of $87.35.

-4000   07/07/2009

$87.35  07/21/2009

Thanks!

Comment: The function works for me - returns 0.466079 in both Excel and in VBA.  (Hopefully that's the correct number - at least it is consistent.)  Have you checked that `IRRValues` and `RepayDates` have both been set up correctly?  Maybe paste into the question a copy of your code that shows how they have been created, plus the Excel formula that you are using to check against.

Comment: @YowE3K, yes that's the answer. the `IRRValues` and `RepayDates` are set up correctly because I even tried to write their data to the worksheet and then calculate the XIRR and it worked. I'll try today and see what's wrong.

Comment: Just because you could write the values out to Excel and it then worked there does **not** mean that they are correct in the arrays - it just means that the translations being performed as the arrays are being populated are being reversed correctly as the arrays are written back to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved!
I thought the array starts at index 1 but it actually starts at 0!